# Using Google Apps Scripts to automate deleting from and inserting data into a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm busy trying to set up a Google Apps script that would run daily to delete all rows from the second row from a google sheet.

Secondly, another Google Apps script must run to insert all rows from one google sheet into the above mentioned google sheet.

Would this be possible using Google Apps scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I user google apps script every day seams 5 year.
I create document (invoice and quote), store them into drive and record them into spreadsheet.

Its works perfectly.

You can insert or delete data as you want.

Please find below a code that insert data in spreadsheet

```
function replace_value_in_spreadsheet(id_spreadsheet,json_that_should_fill_the_table){

 // open spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id_spreadsheet);

 // open the sheet
  var feuilleDuTableau = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet name where insert data");

 // get the last column
  var last_column = feuilleDuTableau.getLastColumn();  

  //get the header of the table
  // this will link the json to the correct column 
  var headers = feuilleDuTableau.getRange(1, 1, 1, last_column).getValues()[0];

  // define the row where insert the data
  var current_row = 2; 

  // get the data
  var current_range = feuilleDuTableau.getRange(current_row , 1, 1, last_column);


  // loop on each column to fill the table
  for (var column_number = 1; column_number <= current_range.getWidth() ; column_number ++ ) {

    // get the correct value
    var key = headers[column_number-1];
    var donnee =  json_that_should_fill_the_table[key];
    var cell = current_range.getCell(1, column_number);

    // set the value
    cell.setValue(donnee);

  }
}
```

Hope it's help